# Merkle tree cannot be calculated in hornet

Tags: iota-network, tangle, compass

I am trying to calculate merkle tree using the below command:sudo -u hornet COO_SEED="$YOURSEED" hornet -d $HORNETPATH tool merkle.

I am getting an error like:sudo: unknown user hornet and sudo :unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: replace `-u hornet` with the user you are running hornet under

Comment: I created a user called hornet and it worked.Thank you.